# Has many through relation, count always returns 0

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a table of companies, a table of addresses and a companiesaddresses table to normalize the many to many relationship. Loopback is working just fine to add a company, add an address to a company and I can even query using the API explorer an address associated with a company using the (POST /Companies/{id}/addresses/{fk}) method.

However, when I try to get all the addresses associated with a company  (GET /Companies/{id}/addresses)  I get back an empty array. Also when I perform a count on how many addresses a particular company has ( GET /Companies/{id}/addresses/count) I always get 0.

I'm sure I'm missing something really tiny. My datasource is postgresql.

```
/* ----- common/models/companies.json ----- */

{
  "name": "Companies",
  "base": "User",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
      "companyName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
   },
     "firstName": {
     "type": "string",
     "required": true
   },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
   },
    "cellNumber": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "addresses": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Addresses",
      "foreignKey": "addressesid",
      "through": "CompaniesAddresses"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}

/* ---- common/models/addresses.json ---- */

{
  "name": "Addresses",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "streetaddress2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phonenumber2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phonenumber1": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "zippostalcode": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "stateprov": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "streetaddress1": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
     "companies": {
       "type": "hasMany",
       "model": "Companies",
       "foreignKey": "companiesid",
       "through": "CompaniesAddresses"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
      {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}

/* ---- companiesaddresses.json ---- */
{
  "name": "CompaniesAddresses",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
   },
  "properties": {
    "companiesid": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "addressesid": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "addresses": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Addresses",
      "foreignKey": "addressesid"
    },
    "companies": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Companies",
      "foreignKey": "companiesid"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}

/* ---- server/boot/model-config.json ---- */

{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Companies": {
    "dataSource": "pg",
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  },
  "Addresses": {
    "dataSource": "pg",
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  },
  "CompaniesAddresses": {
    "dataSource": "pg",
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign keys in companies and addresses are as follows:

`**common/models/companies.json**
 "relations": {
    "addresses": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Addresses",
      "foreignKey": "addressesid", <---- this should be companiesid
      "through": "CompaniesAddresses"
    }
  }`

On the flip side (addresses) do the same modification, all will work.